# How can I find a class in a div and add that class to a string variable?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to find a class using jQuery and store that class in a string. Each class is dynamic but all starts with the same string 'video-'.

Ultimately I want to strip the video- from the class and just use the remaining string as an identifier for my array I have built. Any help is welcome thanks!

```
<div class="background-of-video video-wb-KMTk">
  <span>
    <img src="">
  </span>
</div>
<script>
  $(".background-of-video span").click(function () {
    var video_id = 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hacking around classes as a string is a recipe for disaster. A much better idea would be to put the `wb-KMTk` value you want to read in to it's own `data` attribute on the element and then you can just read that directly when needed

Comment: I would love to do that. but unfortunately the web page builder i'm using for my current job gives me very little flexibility on what i can and cannot add to the divs. right now all i can do is add classes to the pre-made sections/rows/divs etc.

Comment: @youngsirx from your comment below, it's not clear you've seen my solution, which does what I suggest. Give a look!

Answer (score 0):

using an attribute video_Id that containe the data is much better, but if you still want to do it this way.

You could use split and slice to get the result you want.

Se here below example

```js
  $(".background-of-video span").click(function () {
   var v = $(this).parent().attr("class")
   .split(" ")[1].split("-").slice(1,3).join("-")
   
   console.log(v)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background-of-video video-wb-KMTk">
  <span>
  
   click here
    <img src="">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Only problem here is `[1].split("-").slice(1,3).join("-")` seems to assume a lot about the classes (i.e., others not in his example).

Comment: The most importend things is that i show how to extract the video id from `video-wb-KMTk`, then he could instead split it how ever he likes. I only saw the example and as i said having an attribute that containe tha id is much better solution

Comment: True, true, about the ID.

Comment: as @D_N there are other classes in my div that i didn't mention that i should have. my entire div looks like this. 

<div class="bluefoot-slide bluefoot-entity slide-1 background-of-video video-wb-KMTk" style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;">

But i think i understand and know how to fix it. 

one last question would i be able to use .contains in this line of code?

Comment: what i ended up using is 

var v = $(this).parent().attr("class")
   .split(" ")[4].split("video-").slice(1,3).join("-")
   
   console.log(v) 

thank you very much

Comment: @youngsirx Do what works for you, but I do suggest an approach that's not tied as closely to current class order.

Comment: @D_N ok i'll try and figure something out that doesn't require the class order. something like this worked var v = $(this).parent().attr("class")
   .split("video-").slice(1,3).join("-")
   
   console.log(v)

Answer (score 0):

Split the `className` property and loop through, [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)ing whether it matches and stripping out the prefix.

```js
$(".background-of-video").click(function() {
   var classes = $(this)[0].className.split(' '); // Now you have an array.
   var videoId = false;

   for ( i = 0; i < classes.length; i++ ) {

     if ( /^video\-/.test(classes[i]) ) {  // test for class w/ prefix
        videoId = classes[i].replace('video-', ''); // strip out prefix to store
     }
   }

   console.log(videoId); // do whatever you need if videoId !== false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background-of-video video-wb-KMTk">
  <span>
  
   click here
    <img src="">
  </span>
</div>
```

Since you say you can only add classes, change the class to something less likely to conflict with something else, so, say, `youngSirVideo-` instead of `video-`.

Comment: Or simply `var videoId = this.className.match(/\bvideo-(.+)\b/)[1];`, assuming there will always be a match.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Very slick! If you put a ternary testing for ` video-` in it might avoid the missing match issue. It's a bit too terse for me, though -- might be my own regex comfort level, but I'd be worried it's not clear what's happening.